laravel project on apache
I have a system built in Laravel, the system tries to perform an INCLUDE to a certain file using a server variable, the variable returns the following path /home/someuser/.... I get an error in PHP that the file is not found, even though it is found, when I tried to enter the folder path of the file via FTP, I found the file and everything OK when the routing was
/DOMAIN/...
But when the path is /home/someuser/domain.
I am getting that the file is not found. I realized that it is a problem with promission access, probably to the home folder and to the user's folder. How can I fix this?
this is the error i am getting

require(/home/affy/domains/****/public_html/vendor/itstructure/laravel-multi-menu/src/../config/multimenu.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

i try to change /home to 777 and /home/affy to 777
i change the ftp setting to allow user outside is folder and now i can get to /home from ftp but i still getting an error

Did you try to change permission actual file multimenu.php

I really don't think changing the home folder permissions to 777 is a good idea.

i know but i tried. i tried to upload the project to antoer server with aapanel but i am getting the same result on my computer everything work with xampp php 8.2
i tried to update php to 8.2 on server but this didnt help

It's better 755 , changing to 777 will expose your folder to public

Can you try this command chmod -R 755 /home/affy
chmod 644 /home/affy/domains/****/public_html/vendor/itstructure/laravel-multi-menu/config/multimenu.php

This could also be an open_basedir issue.

same result on 755 and 644

i am also thinking it open_basedir but didnt find a solution

So, what is your open_basedir setting?

[affy]
user = $pool
group = $pool
listen = /usr/local/php81/sockets/$pool.sock
listen.owner = $pool
listen.group = apache
listen.mode = 660
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 10
pm.process_idle_timeout = 20
pm.max_requests = 500
php_admin_value[sendmail_path] = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f affy@affy.co.il
php_admin_value[session.save_path] = /home/affy/tmp
php_admin_value[open_basedir] = /home/affy/:/tmp/:/var/tmp/:/opt/alt/php81/usr/share/pear/:/dev/urandom:/usr/local/php81/lib/:/usr/local/php81/lib/:/usr/local/php82/lib/:/usr/local/lib/php/

It's better to add something like that to the question, with a bit of explanation, and format it there properly. Anyway, does /home/affy/ work, but other /home/someuser/ do not?

NO if the route without /home/affy/ its ok but the SERVER ROOT DOCUMENT return it with /home/affy/ and i cant change it.

just fount in the error log this

[Tue Nov 05 11:01:55.722370 2024] [autoindex:error] [pid 3387129:tid 3387156] [remote 5.29.15.79:23387] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/affy/domains/***/private_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.htm,index.shtml,index.php,index.phtml) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

If project is under Home directory, try
require __DIR__ . '/../storage/utils/multimenu-config/multimenu.php';

Rather than changing the permission of the home directory, you can try creating a symlink to the folder where your file is located
create a utils folder in your project root and create the symlink in there
mkdir -p /home/affy/domains/your-domain/public_html/storage/utils

now create a symlink in here
ln -s /home/affy/domains/your-domain/public_html/vendor/itstructure/laravel-multi-menu/config /home/affy/domains/your-domain/public_html/utils/multimenu-config

everything inside laravel-multi-menu/config is now available in /utils/multimenu-config, now you can either use it directly or use composer to load them.
try this
require base_path('storage/utils/multimenu-config/multimenu.php');

I this example should work , normally these kinds of problems can be seen in wsl base development .

but the problem is when the LARAVEL try to require the file it use /home/affy....
and this route isnt accusable if you try to enter the folder without /home/affy it is fine but the server return it with the /home/affy

I have updated the answer , try it this way you should be able to access the file

i dont know were laravel require the file i think it doing it with auto loader

Have you tried looking in the logs

the error come from this file
public / index.php: 52
and this is the line
$request = Request::capture()

yes i look at the php log

i understand the if i will require the file like that it will work
require(/domains/****/public_html/vendor/itstructure/laravel-multi-menu/src/../config/multimenu.php):
but the SERVER_ROOT_DOCUMENT return the full route with /home/affy
